# floating point notation about 0.xxxx numbers. ex. 13.625

Tags: floating-point

i read a book that said in floating point notation,
we move the decimal point of the binary number and
then store this decimal point in the mantissa.
However, in binary system, there is only 1 number above the decimal point.
If the number above the decimal point is 0, in the case of a number such as 0.1,
the number above the decimal point is 0.
How is it handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0.1 as a float would be 1.0 x 2^(-1), so it is represented as such: 1.0 (BTW, that part is always 1.xxx..., in fact since that 1 is always there it is actually not stored at all) along with the -1 (the mantissa) are stored.

Comment: "since that 1 is always there"  --> Hmmm, how to encode 0.0 then?  Perhaps not _always_.

Comment: ya got me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: it might be better to say that the 1 is implied for every exponent except the smallest and largest. "subnormals" fall into this lower range, and occurs when the binary representation of their exponent is all zeros (numerically this is treated as -1023 for binary64s and -127 for binary32s)